# TypeError when using "tf.while_loop" : 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, while-loop

I am training an unsupervised CNN, for this, I defined a loss function in which CNN input is mapped to the cnn output through a complicated expression. I am using `tf.while_loop` to update the variables of `gamma_tilde_tensor_local` and `D_mat_tensor_local`. I have uploaded my code & the error below.
please suggest me how to update tensor variables in `while_loop`.

To avoid confusion, I have avoided the complex loops. originally `gamma_tilde_tensor_local` size `(batch_size, M,M,K,K)`.

```
def function(self):
    gamma_tilde_tensor_local = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape = [self.mini_batchSize, self.num_users]),dtype=tf.float32)
    D_mat_tensor_local = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape = [self.mini_batchSize, , self.num_users]), dtype=tf.float32)
    condition_g1  = lambda k_iter1, gamma_tilde_tensor_local, D_mat_tensor_local : k_iter1 < self.num_users
    def body_gm1( k_iter1, gamma_tilde_tensor_local, D_mat_tensor_local):
        tf_x_k = tf.expand_dims(self.PHI_batch[:,:,k_iter1],axis=-1)          
        tf_x_kd = tf.expand_dims(self.PHI_batch[:,:,k_iter2],axis=-1)        
        phi_to_reduce =  tf.matmul( tf.transpose(tf_x_kd, perm=[0, 2, 1]), tf_x_k)
        phi_t = tf.squeeze(phi_to_reduce,[1,2])
        gamma_till = tf.divide(  tf.multiply( self.gammafun[:,1, 2 ], self.channel_Gain[:,1, k_iter1]), self.channel_Gain[:,1, 2])
        gamma_tilde_tensor_local[: k_iter1] = tf.multiply(phi_t, gamma_till )    
        D_mat_tensor_local[:,k_iter1] = tf.sqrt(  tf.multiply( self.gammafun[1, 2], self.channel_Gain[1,k_iter1] ))                 

        return tf.add(k_iter1, 1), gamma_tilde_tensor_local, D_mat_tensor_local
    k_iter1, gamma_tilde_tensor_local, D_mat_tensor_local = tf.while_loop(condition_g1, body_gm1, [0, gamma_tilde_tensor_local, D_mat_tensor_local])
```

Giving error at the line:
`gamma_tilde_tensor_local[: k_iter1] = tf.multiply(phi_t, gamma_till )`.